# Plotting multiple images side by side using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

l have 21 images stored in my folder `path="home/images"` that l want to visualize in one figure.

how can l do that such that for each plot has a title  ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by using glob:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('home/images*.gif'): #assuming gif
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
```

Then plot them following some example like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111525/how-to-show-multiple-images-in-one-figure)
See more examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276066/python-plot-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-figure)