# Unexpected displaying multiple images with skimage io submodule

Tags: jupyter-notebook, scikit-image

Hi, I'm trying to display multiple images in jupyter's iPython's notebook.
I'm using `skimage.io.imshow()` function to display each of it. I don't want to use `skimage.io.imshow_collection()` beacause it displays image with a smaller resolution

This is my code:

```
io.imshow(x_i)
io.imshow(z_i_norm)
io.imshow(x_prime_i_norm)
io.imshow(y_i)
```

This is the result: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6xyS.png)

[image]

I'm expecting to display all images in just one output box

Thanks

Comment: Jupyter just displays the result of the final comment executed in a cell. So `io.imshow` doesn't really "show" anything, but rather returns data which Jupyter knows how to show. So you can't chain them like that. Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/q/17111525

Comment: Thanks, the link that you provide me was useful for me, but finally I applied the last solution given in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471814/display-multiple-images-in-one-ipython-notebook-cell/27795087